# identifying real function from a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

Given a function $f:S\subset \mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, we can write $f(z)=u(z)+iv(z)$, where $z \mapsto u(z)$ and $z \mapsto v(z)$, but then we I look at problems, I dont know where to start,

example:$f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ , is the the real part of the function $u(z)=1/Re(z)$ and $v(z)=1/Im(z)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you are asking, but I think I understand. The idea should be to write $z=x+iy$ and then do some algebra and get the function as $u(z)+iv(z)$. So let's look at your example of $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$, we first write $f(z)=\frac{1}{x+iy}$, and then we just break up the function into a real part plus an imaginary part that is
$$
\frac{1}{x+iy}=\frac{1}{x+iy}\frac{x-iy}{x-iy}=\frac{x-iy}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}-\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}i
$$
Thus, we find that we have that $f(z)=u(z)+iv(z)$ where
$$
u(z)=\frac{\Re(z)}{\vert z\vert^2}
$$
and we have that
$$
v(z)=-\frac{\Im(z)}{\vert z\vert^2}
$$
Is this what you were asking about?